# How to add swap memory in kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes, memory

I need to add swap memory in kubernates pod. so that if any pods exceeds the available RAM then it can use the swap memory from hard disk. is that possible in kubernates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official Kubernetes prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) says that:

> Swap disabled. You MUST disable swap in order for the kubelet to work
> properly.

You are supposed to use cpu/memory limits for deployments. Kubelet is not designed to handle swap situations. If memory swapping is allowed to occur on a host system, it can lead to performance and stability issues within Kubernetes.

However there is a way to disable swap while installing `kubeadm`:

- Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/20-allow-swap.conf` with the following content:

`[Service] Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"`

- Execute:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

- Run `kubeadm` with flag `--ignore-preflight-errors=Swap`:

`kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap`

Bear in mind however that it is not a recommended way.

Answer (score 4):

As of *Kubernetes 1.22*, swap memory is supported (as an alpha feature).

1. Configure the node's host OS with a swap memory device (e.g., with `swapon` or `/etc/fstab`);
2. Configure kubelet on that node to:

   - still start despite detecting the presence of swap (disable `fail-on-swap`),
   - enable the `NodeSwap` feature gate, and
   - configure `MemorySwap.SwapBehavior=UnlimitedSwap` to let kubernetes workloads use swap memory.

Note, there is currently no support for setting swap limits individually per workload (although this is planned for the beta). Either no containers are permitted to use any swap, or all containers can use unlimited swap memory.

(If workloads are *not* permitted to use swap then, depending on the Linux kernel cgroups version, they could still get swapped anyway. Prior to cgroups v2, processes were not able to enforce separate limits for swap and physical memory, but only for the combined total.)

See the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#swap-memory), and the kubernetes enhancement proposal (KEP) cited therein, for more details.

Comment: As of Kubernetes v1.28, this is now beta: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#swap-memory

Answer (score 0):

I would like the pods to have swap inside the container,  not on the host..    if the application uses too much memory  the kernal restarts the service..  if the container restarts  then it lessens uptime right..  swap can assist in that

Answer (score 0):

Enabling swap on a node is already covered by previous answers.

If you need to control which pods and containers can be swapped and to what extent, you can install [the nri-memory-qos plugin](https://containers.github.io/nri-plugins/stable/docs/memory/memory-qos.html) to your cluster. This allows controlling swap on container level with [annotations](https://containers.github.io/nri-plugins/stable/docs/memory/memory-qos.html#workload-configuration).

```
helm repo add nri-plugins https://containers.github.io/nri-plugins
helm install nri-memory-qos nri-plugins/nri-memory-qos --set nri.patchRuntimeConfig=true --namespace kube-system
```